# mongoexport fields from subdocuments to csv

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to export a field from a subdocument with no luck.
Here is my syntax;

```
mongoexport -d test -c accounts -f account_number,situses.coordinates -o coordinates.csv --type=csv
```

The output includes the account_number but not the coordinates field from the subdocument.
According to the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#options), this is supposed to work.

The following will export the entire situses subdocument, but I only want the one field.

```
mongoexport -d test -c accounts -f account_number,situses -o coordinates.csv --type=csv
```

Am I just referencing the subdocument field wrong or something?

I'm running Mongodb 3.0.4

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

The following syntax worked on an earlier version of Mongodb (2.6.x ?).  Notice the `subdoc.0.fieldname` syntax.

```
mongoexport -d test -c accounts -f account_number,situses.0.coordinates -o coordinates.csv --csv
```

It appears support for directly referencing a subdocument has been removed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is mistake in your syntax.

> From mongo version 3.0.0, mongoexport removed the --type = csv option. Use the --type=csv option to specify CSV format for the output.

You should use :

```
mongoexport --db tests --collection accounts --type=csv --fields account_number,situses --out coordinates.csv
```

**For nested fields you should use :**

```
mongoexport --db tests --collection accounts --csv --fields 'account_number,situses.0.coordinates'  --out /home/vishwas/c1.csv
```

**EDIT for mongo 3.0 with sub documents:**

You need to create separate collection with required fields from subdocuments like -

```
db.test.aggregate({"$unwind":"$situses"},{"$project":{"_id":0,"account_number":1,"siteUsesCo":"$situses.coordinates"}},{"$out" : "forcsv"})
```

If you want **only one field** from subdocument then use aggregation like -

```
db.test.aggregate({"$unwind":"$situses"},{"$limit":1},{"$project":{"_id":0,"account_number":1,"siteUsesCo":"$situses.coordinates"}},{"$out" : "forcsv"})
```

And then export from `forcsv` collection like-

```
mongoexport --db test --collection forcsv --csv --fields 'account_number,siteUsesCo'  --out coordinates.csv
```

And after exporting delete collection `forcsv`.

Comment: I was already using --type=csv and changing from -f to --fields made no difference.

Comment: Your sample code references the subdocument, not the field in the subdocument.  When referencing subdoc.fieldname it does not work.  Which  conflicts with the documentation.

Comment: @SteveO7 please try out my edit. It is working for nested fields also.

Comment: I suspect you may be on version 2.x.  See my update to the original question.

Comment: @SteveO7 My bad. M using mongo 2.x. I found one way to export by creating a seperate collection of required fields and then export that collection. please see my edit.

Comment: thanks for help!   I was heading in that direction and your example helps a lot!  You can see my post that this is a known bug.

Answer (score 1):

And one more solution, where you can configure output in flexible way

```
mongo host:port/test --quiet query.js -u username -p passw0rd > accounts.csv
```

and query.js:

```
db = db.getSiblingDB('test');

db.getCollection('accounts').find({}, {account_number:1, situses:1, _id:0}).forEach(
    function(item_data) { print(`${item_data.account_number},${item_data.situses[0].coordinates}`); });
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a known bug to be fixed in 3.0.5.
See this; https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-657