# Export array of documents from MongoDB in csv

Tags: mongodb, csv

I'm working on a java program to pass from MongoDB to Neo4j.
I have to export some Mongo documents in a csv file. 
I have, for example, this document:

```
"coached_Team" : [ 
        {
            "team_id" : "Pal.00",
            "in_charge" : {
                "from" : {
                    "day" : 25,
                    "month" : 9,
                    "year" : 2013
                }
            },
            "matches" : 75
        }
]
```

I have to export in csv. I read some other questions, for example [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/459042/mongoexport-csv-output-array-values) and I used that tip to export my document.

To export in csv I use this command:

```
Z:\path\to\Mongo\3.0\bin>mongoexport --db <database> --collection
<collection> --type=csv --fields coached_Team.0.team_id,coached_Team.0.in_charge.from.day,
coached_Team.0.in_charge.from.month,coached_Team.0.in_charge.from.year,
coached_Team.0.matches --out "C:\path\to\output\file\output.csv
```

But, it did not work for me:
[image]

Comment: This is due to [bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-657). You can use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30903293/mongoexport-fields-from-subdocuments-to-csv/30906709#30906709) to export nested collection. The bug is fixed in mongo version  3.0.5, 3.1.4.

Comment: In my case the solution of that post does not work. When you use the $unwind you can't project the _id of each document. I need the _id to import the document into Neo4j. However I dowloaded MongoDB 3.0.5 and like you say the bug is fixed. Thank you.