# MongoDB export issue

Tags: mongodb, csv

I am trying to export the MongoDB output to CSV format. But have trouble.
See the following document in my collection:

```
 db.save.find().pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("58884b11e1370511b89d8267"),
        "domain" : "google.com",
        "emails" : [
                {
                        "email" : "f@google.com",
                        "first" : "James",
                        "Last" : "fer"
                },
                {
                        "email" : "d@gmail.com",
                        "first" : "dear",
                        "last" : "near"
                }
        ]
}
```

### Exporting the document to csv

```
C:\MongoDB\Server\bin>mongoexport.exe -d Trial -c save -o file.csv --type csv --fields domain,emails
2017-01-25T12:50:54.927+0530    connected to: localhost
2017-01-25T12:50:54.929+0530    exported 1 record
```

The output file is:

```
domain,emails
google.com,"[{""email"":""f@google.com"",""first"":""James"",""Last"":""fer""},{""email"":""d@gmail.com"",""first"":""dear"",""last"":""near""}]"
```

### But if I import the same file, the output is different then it was in the actual collection. See the example:

```
> db.sir.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5888529fa26b65ae310d026f"),
        "domain" : "google.com",
        "emails" : "[{\"email\":\"f@google.com\",\"first\":\"James\",\"Last\":\"fer\"},{\"email\":\"d@gmail.com\",\"first\":\"dear\",\"last\":\"near\"}]"
}
```

I do not want that extra `\` in my import document. That's it. Please tell me if it is avoidable and if yes, then what should be the format of CSV to be given for import.
This is not expected format. So let me know how I can make the proper format. Kindly help me with this query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongoexport fields from subdocuments to csv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30903293/mongoexport-fields-from-subdocuments-to-csv)

Comment: CSV doesn't have conception of child object! you've to change your format!

Comment: Kindly, read my question carefully. I have a different problem please check it.