# How to mongoexport with one field

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

i have a few fields in my collection at the mongoDB.
i have tried exported out everything. 
which looking like this

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5a5ef05dbe83813f55141a51"},"comments_data":{"id":"211","comments":{"paging":{"cursors":{"after":"WzZANVFV4TlRVME5qUXpPUT09","before":"WTI5dEF4TlRVNE1USTVNemczTXpZAMk56YzZANVFV4TlRBMU9ERTFNQT09"}},"data":[{"created_time":"2018-01-04T09:29:09+0000","message":"Super","from":{"name":"M Mun","id":"1112"},"id":"1111"},{"created_time":"2018-01-07T22:25:08+0000","message":"Happy bday..Godbless you...","from":{"name":"L1","id":"111"},"id":"1111"},{"created_time":"2018-01-10T00:22:00+0000","message":"Nelson ","from":{"name":"Boon C","id":"1111"},"id":"10111"},{"created_time":"2018-01-10T01:07:19+0000","message":"Thank to SingTel I like to","from":{"name":"Sarkar WI","id":"411653482605703"},"id":"10155812413346677_10155825869201677"}]}},"post_id":"28011986676_10155812413346677","post_message":"\"Usher in the New Year with deals and rewards that will surely perk you up, exclusively for Singtel customers. Find out more at singtel.com/rewards\"",
```

but now i want to export just a single field which is the 'message' from the 'comments_data' from the collection.

i tried using this `mongoexport --db sDB --collection sTest --fields data.comments_data --out test88.json`

but when i check my exported file, it just contains something like this

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5a5ef05dbe83813f55141a51"}}
```

which is something not i have expected.
i just want something like `"message":"Happy bday..Godbless you..."`
but when i query out at the mongoshell with `db.sTest.find({}, {comments_data:1, _id:0})`i can roughly get what i want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this ...

```
db.sTest.find({}, {'comments_data.message':1, _id:0})
```

... selects the data you are interested in then the equivalent `mongoexport` command is:

```
mongoexport --db sDB --collection sTest --fields 'comments_data.message' --type csv --out test88.csv
```

Note: this uses `--type csv` because, according to [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption-mongoexport-fields), use of the JSON output format causes MongoDB to export all fields in the selected sub document ...

> For csv output formats, mongoexport includes only the specified field(s), and the specified field(s) can be a field within a sub-document.
>
> For JSON output formats, mongoexport includes only the specified field(s) and the _id field, and if the specified field(s) is a field within a sub-document, the mongoexport includes the sub-document with all its fields, not just the specified field within the document.

If you must have JSON format and limit your output to a single field then I think you'll need to write the reduced documents to a separate collection and export *that* collection, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30906709/8200937).

Comment: The exported output is what? Your last comment didn't include an example of the revised exported output ....

Comment: thanks ! but now the exported output have fields of _id, oid, comments_data, comments, before, data, message. So many fields infront of the 'message'. isit possible to remove the  _id and oid?

Comment: db version v3.4.10

Comment: Apologies, I have now corrected the answer. If you re-read the answer you'll see that this is an result of using the JSON output format. If you can choose CSV instead then this will _just work_. Otherwise you'll need to do something like write cutdown documents to a separate collection and export that collection in JSON format.

Comment: hi i also tried exported out in csv file, it still have the _id. But it's ok. Thanks!