# MongoExport using a query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoexport

when i try to get data out from mongoDB. i am able to show what i want to achieve using this query

```
db.sInsert.distinct(
    "comments_data.comments.data.message", 
    {post_id: {"$eq": "28011986676" }}
)
```

where the result is

```
[ "Who else loves Apple ?" ]
```

Additionally this is how, my document looks like

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a43aa19d4b45e362428e2da"),
        "comments_data" : {
                "id" : "28011986676_10155780942281677",
                "comments" : {
                        "paging" : {
                                "cursors" : {
                                        "after" : "WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZAFhKemIzSTZAN4TlRBeE5EWXlPQT09",
                                        "before" : "WTI5dGJXVnVk4TVRZAMk56YzZANVFV4TlRBeE5EWXlPQT09"
                                }
                        },
                        "data" : [
                                {
                                        "created_time" : "2018-01-03T21:23:47+0000",
                                        "message" : "Poor customer care service after became the Singtel customer.I did my          re contract they send acknowledgement email confirmation after no followup.I called again and remains no proper response and action extremely worst customer care service.",
                                        "from" : {
                                                "name" : "Sundararaju G",
                                                "id" : "1020391"
                                        },
                                        "id" : "10155780942281677_10155811924116677"
                                }
                        ]
                }
        },
        "post_id" : "28011986676_10155780942281677",
        "post_message" : "\"Singtel TV celebrated our 10th birthday with 10 awesome experiences for our customers! Each of our winners won a trip of a lifetime - from attending the Emmy Awards, getting a magical princess treatment at Disneyland, to catching a Premier League game live in London! We thank all our customers for your support and we look forward to more great years to come!\"",
        "reactions_data" : {
                "reactions" : {
                        "paging" : {
                                "cursors" : {
                                        "after" : "TVRBd01EQXpNVEF5T1Rje4TXc9PQZDZD",
                                        "before" : "TVRjNE56TTBBek56a3hNek14TWc9PQZDZD"
                                },
                                "next" : "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/280119866761677/reactions?access_token=EAA"
                        },
                        "data" : [
                                {
                                        "type" : "ANGRY",
                                        "id" : "1020573391",
                                        "name" : "Sundararaju Gh"
                                },
                                {
                                        "type" : "LIKE",
                                        "id" : "64721496",
                                        "name" : "Zhiang Xian"
                                }
                        ]
                },
                "id" : "28011986676_102281677"
        }
}
```

But when i tried to export it out, with this sentence below. I am experiencing error

```
mongoexport --db sDB --collection sInsert --query '{"post_id":{$gte:28011986676}}',{ comments_data.comments.data.message}' --out test.json
```

Where the error message is

```
2018-01-29T19:56:31.442+0800    too many positional arguments: [comments_data.comments.data.message}']
2018-01-29T19:56:31.526+0800    try 'mongoexport --help' for more information
```

May i ask, is it possible to export out what i want to achieve like how i can show in the mongodb?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This part of your mongoexport command ...

```
--query '{"post_id":{$gte:28011986676}}',{ comments_data.comments.data.message}'
```

... suggests that you are trying to specify the filter **and** projections by using the `query` parameter. According to [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption-mongoexport-query) the `query` parameter:

> Provides a JSON document as a query that optionally limits the documents returned in the export.

So, that's only for the filter.

You can use the `fields` parameter to limit the output to specific field(s). From [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption-mongoexport-fields):

> Specifies a field or fields to include in the export. Use a comma separated list of fields to specify multiple fields.

So, your `mongoexport` command should be:

```
mongoexport --db sDB --collection sInsert --query '{"post_id":{$gte:28011986676}}' --fields "comments_data.comments.data.message" --out test.json
```

However, since you have chosen JSON output format the following (from the docs) is relevant:

> For JSON output formats, mongoexport includes only the specified field(s) and the _id field, and if the specified field(s) is a field within a sub-document, the mongoexport includes the sub-document with all its fields, not just the specified field within the document.

Since you are attempted to select a specific field from a sub document **and** using JSON output format, `mongoexport` will include "the sub-document with all its fields, not just the specified field within the document".

This sounds very like the issue raised in an [earlier question from you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48296724/how-to-mongoexport-with-one-field).

Comment: Thanks, cause i want to try to export two fields together. anyway i tried the answer proposed by u. but i still experiencing error of 2018-01-29T21:47:09.547+0800    too many positional arguments: [28011986676_10155782651991677}}']

Comment: Hi, i managed to solve by myself. 
mongoexport --db sDB --collection sInsert --query "{'post_id':{$gte: '28011986676'}}" --fields "comments_data.comments.data.message" --out test.json.

but why it does not group by the post_id?

may i ask, if i exported out in json, there is no other way not to include all of its fields right ?

Comment: Re this: "if i exported out in json, there is no other way not to include all of its fields right" ... yes, that's correct. Re this: "why it does not group by the post_id" ... you ran a query, without any grouping, so the result is not grouped.

Comment: if i put '{"post_id":{$gte:28011986676}}', it does not group by 28011986676?

Comment: You keep using the term `group by` but I don't think you are using that term correctly. This query: `{"post_id":{$gte:28011986676}}` will return all docs having post_id with a value >= 28011986676. This is not a "group by". Also, looking at the doc in your question the `post_id` attribute is a string not a number so the `>=` operator does not apply. Are you perhaps looking for all docs having a `post_id` which **starts with**  28011986676? If so, then the correct filter is: `{"post_id":{$regex: /^28011986676/}}`

Comment: Thank you very much! so sorry for the trouble. $regex is the correct filter. so sorry for the trouble, as i am very new to mongodb. still trying to figure out how to use it. Once again, thank you!

Comment: No problem, best of luck.